# Como fazer o "adapter.getItemPosition" pegar apenas parte da String e esconder a outra parte na hora de apresentar o ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Eu tenho um listView que retorna duas strings para uma cada linha. O código e o nome de um país, eu não gostaria de apresentar o código mas preciso dele para quando o usuário clicar na linha pegar o código e fazer uma busca no banco. Minha linha está assim "345 Brasil", por precisar do código eu precisava pegar apenas ele com o `adapter.getItem(position)`. Existe alguma maneira de fazer isso? Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponho que o seu *adapter* seja do tipo `ArrayAdapter<String>` e daí a sua dificuldade.
A minha sugestão é que declare uma classe chamada *Pais* e declare o *Adapter* como `ArrayList<Pais>`.

Comece por declarar a classe *Pais* :

```
public class Pais{
    String nome;
    String codigo;

    public Pais(String nome, String codigo){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome(){

        return nome;
    }

    public String getCodigo(){

        return codigo;
    }
}
```

Declare o *array*, que é usado pelo *Adapter*, como `ArrayList<Pais>` e passe-o ao `ArrayAdapter<Pais>`.

Quando necessitar do nome do país faça: `getItem(position).getNome();`
Quando necessitar do código do país faça: `getItem(position).getCodigo();`

Comment: obrigado, acho que é isso mesmo que eu preciso!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode salvar o objecto inteiro no seu `Adapter`, em seu objecto você implementa o `toString` que é o método que o `Adapter` vai usar para mostrar no `ListView`, e quando você precisar obter o código por exemplo você tem o objeto salvo com todos os seus atributos.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi o problema galera, ficou meu gambiarra mas funcionou, agora eu pego só o número da string `adapter.getItem(position).replaceAll("[^0-9]*", "");`
Mas teria como eu esconder este número? Apresentar só o nome do país?